# C# asp.net Get Ipv4 ip address of a client

Tags: c#, asp.net

My below code is getting ivp6 ip address am not sure how to get ipv4 in the same manner.

```
 string ipAddress = "";
           if (Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()).Length > 0)
           {
               ipAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName())[0].ToString();
           }
```

Comment: `Dns.GetHostName()` has nothing to do with the client.

Comment: `string strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
IPHostEntry ipEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName); IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;` In IPAddress array you can will get both the IP'S IPV4 and IPV6

Answer (score 2):

This code:
    Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName())

Will return an array of all IP addresses assigned to the local machine. When you assign to the ipAddress variable, you are using "[0]", which only takes the first IP address in the list.

Look at the entire array and you might find that you are indeed getting the IPv4 addresses too.

Comment: Thanks for sharing ur  knowledge but how to do that ma not sure

Comment: Take at look at the example in the documentation for [GetHostAddresses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses(v=vs.110).aspx). It shows how to loop through the results.